# Unittest for opts passed to mock

Tags: unit-testing, go, testify

I have some code, for instance:

```golang
type FileFilter func(*models.File) bool

func ByExtension(ext string) FileFilter {
    return func(file *models.File) bool {
        // it's just an example do not blame here :)
        return true
    }
}

type FileManager interface {
    ReadAllBy(ctx context.Context, path models.Path, filters ...FileFilter) ([]*models.File, error)
}

func Service() {
  // do smth (get struct which implements FileManager interface)
  fileManger.ReadAllBy(ctx, path", ByExtension("log"))
  // do smth
}
```

And I want to test `Service` function.
I use `testify` lib and `mockery` for generate mocks.

Is it possible to check that I pass correct filters in `ReadAllBy` method?

This is a piece of my unittest:

```golang
fileManagerMock.EXPECT().
    ReadAllBy(params.ctx, path, mock.AnythingOfType("FileFilter")).Return(files, nil)
```

This test works, but it will not fail i pass wrong `FilterFilter` opt.

Comment: What does "it will not fail i pass wrong FilterFilter opt" mean? You're passing a mock, what would a "wrong" mock be?

Comment: I'm not passing mock. I'm passing opt to some method, which is mock in unittest